# angular2 child route, no component

Tags: angular

I'm trying to make an 'edit' url for my entity. So, for example `/my-site/entity/1` and `/my-site/entity/1/edit`. The `edit` part is just used to toggle a state of the main/parent entity url.

In angular 1, with the ui-router I could do something along the lines of

```
.state("home.entity.edit", {
    url: "/edit",
    reloadOnSearch: false
})
```

I.e. this would be child state of `home.entity`. It would have no view or controller as the parent state would handle it. Also on toggle to this state, nothing would actually happen in terms of redirect/controller execution.

Is it actually possible to do this with the component router in angular2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the moment, I've implemented it as follows

```
{
    path: 'view/:id',
    component: NotesViewComponent,
    children: [
        {
            path: '',
            component: null
        },
        {
            path: 'edit',
            canActivate: [EditModeActivator],
            component: null
        }
    ],
    data: {
        editMode: false
    }
}
```

where

```
@Injectable()
class EditModeActivator implements CanActivate {
    constructor() { }

    canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
        if (next.url[0].path === "edit") {
            let data: any = next.parent.data;
            data.editMode = true;
        }

        return true
    } 
}
```

It is a hack yes, but will do for now!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible using Router parameters. 
The edit parameter will be an [optional parameter](https://angular.io/guide/router#optional-route-parameters). In your ngOnInit you will read the params from the request, and act accordingly.
It's slightly less automated than your example, but it gives more freedom as well.

Comment: I would want the optional parameter to be a part of the path fragment however, not as a query string.

Comment: Alternatively you can point the same route (/edit/:id and /show/:id) to the same component?

Comment: The latest version of the Router uses something called matrix url notation (localhost:3000/heroes;id=15;foo=foo) where the parameters are part of the path fragment and not in the query string. It's pretty interesting and how I would recommend solving this problem .